# Finding Voltage Thevenin via short circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, thevenin

I found this question online where \$ R_1 = R_2 = R_3 = R_4 = 15 \Omega \$ and \$V_s = 15 V\$

[image]

Finding \$R_{th}\$ first, we short circuit \$V_s\$,

We know \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are in parallel which is then in series with \$R_3\$ which is then in parallel with \$R_4\$.

Substituting 15 ohms for all R values we get \$R_{th} = 9 \Omega\$

Now we want to find \$V_th\$
I attempt to do this by using the \$i_{sc}\$ short circuit method. By connecting the two terminals, I think we are short circuiting the \$R_4\$ wire
So, applying ohm's law: \$V_{s} = R_{1,2,3} * i_{sc}\$

where \$R_{1,2,3}\$ is the equivalent resistance of \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, \$R_3\$

Finding \$R_{1,2,3}\$, \$R_{1,2,3} = 22.5 \Omega\$

Solving for \$I_{sc}\$

$$V_S = R_{1,2,3} * i_{sc}$$

$$15V = 22.5\Omega *  i_{sc}$$

$$i_{sc} = \frac {2}{3}$$

So, \$V_{th}\$ should just be \$R_{Th}\$ times \$i_{sc}\$

$$V = R_{Th} * i_{sc}$$

$$V = 9\Omega * \frac {2}{3}$$

$$V = 6V$$

However, my answer is incorrect(as given by the answer checker. Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: FYI, EE uses `\$` instead of `$` to start and end inline math.

Comment: Isn't Rth = R1+(R2^-1+(R3+R4)^-1)^-1 = 25?, It has been some years since I have done this :)

Comment: @Sorenp, to get Rth you need to look at it from the output port, not from the voltage source. OP has calculated Rth correctly: ((R1 || R2) + R3) || R4.

Comment: @The Photon time to dust of the old notes, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your \$I_{sc}\$ is the current produced by the source \$V_S\$ when the output is shorted.

It isn't the current that goes through the short.

Comment: Just making sure I understand what you're saying, my current \$i_{sc}\$ is the total current through the shorted circuit? But in reality, I should be using the current that is going through the shorted wire I put in?

Comment: @WilsonGuo, there's no "current through the whole circuit". There's current through different branches of the circuit. You calculated the current through the branch with the voltage source. What you want is the current through the short (which will be the same as the current through R3).

Comment: I'm not sure how to the current through the short(aka the current through \$R_3\$). When I short circuit the terminals, no current flows through resistors \$ R_2 \$ and  \$ R_4 \$

Comment: Therefore, the current flows through \$ R_1 \$ \$ R_3 \$ in series so the current through both of them are the same.

Comment: Re-draw the circuit with the short applied across the outputs. What makes you think there's no current through R2?

Comment: sorry I meant \$ R_2 \$

Comment: Re draw the circuit with the short. What makes you think there's no current through R2? You should actually see that R2 and R3 are in parallel. So if there's current through R3 there must also be current through R2.

Comment: Ah! I see the only resistor that is "shorted" is \$ R_4 \$. 

Now, attempting to find the current through \$ R_3 \$, we see that since \$ R_3 \ = R_2$ the current should be same through the two branches.

Comment: I'm not sure where to go from there. I want to say that the current through \$ R_3 \$ is just half the total current, but I'm not sure how to go about solving for the total current

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99455/discussion-between-wilson-guo-and-the-photon).

Comment: Again, I don't like the term "total current", but you already solved for it. That's what you got from your original calculation.

Comment: AAAAAHHHHHHH!!! Everything just connected in my head! I'm getting the current to be 3Amps which is the correct answer!

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me understand and solve this problem. I know you didn't have to spend your time doing this. I appreciate all you've done and wish you a good day!

Comment: You mean 0.333... A, right?

Comment: Sorry I meant \$ V_{th}  = 3V\$, but yes \$ i_{sc} = \frac {1}{3}A \$

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsZm0v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Finding first \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we need to look at:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAOH2H.png)</sup>

Now, we see that:

$$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{R}_4\cdot\left(\frac{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}+\text{R}_3\right)}{\text{R}_4+\frac{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}+\text{R}_3}\tag1$$

Finding secondly \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we need to look at:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuOSQG.png)</sup>

$$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}\left(t\right)}{\text{R}_1+\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}}\tag2$$

So:

$$\text{V}_\text{th}=\text{R}_\text{th}\cdot\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{R}_4\cdot\left(\frac{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}+\text{R}_3\right)}{\text{R}_4+\frac{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}+\text{R}_3}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}\left(t\right)}{\text{R}_1+\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}}\tag3$$

Comment: Are you sure about your Rth?

Comment: @G36 Sorry, edited my answer.